# Access nested keys using nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a requirement that, I want to make a list of keys and return using nodejs.

Here is my json structure:

```
{
        type: "qwqw",
        org: "asdasd",
        pop: "asaswe",
        results: {
            "resultId1": {
                "type": "normal"
                .............
                ..............
             },
             "resultId2": {
                "type": "normal"
                .............
                ..............
             },
             "resultId3": {
                "type": "normal"
                .............
                ..............
             }
       }
```

So here, desired outcome is; something like this `["resultId1", "resultId2", "resultId3"]`

This is what I tried :

```
 var keys = Object.keys(jsonString.results);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[keys[i]]);
    }
```

Could someone help me with the json parsing using any nodejs library;

Comment: Before voting down, please comment it; so that I can correct it.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your desired output?

Comment: Updated the question; please check

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: You've already solved your problem. `var keys = Object.keys(jsonString.results);`

Comment: I am getting undefined as  a result;

Comment: Could you include your whole code in your question ? (Including the way to import your data) **Edit :** By the way, your `for` loop is completly useless. just print the `keys` variable.

Comment: @Seblor, It worked.

Answer (score 2):

you should try this, as it is quite simple to get keys in javascript.

```js
var data =  {
                type: "qwqw",
                org: "asdasd",
                pop: "asaswe",
                results: {
                    "resultId1": {
                        "type": "normal"
                     },
                     "resultId2": {
                        "type": "normal"
                     },
                     "resultId3": {
                        "type": "normal"
                     }
                }
           };
           
var output = Object.keys(data.results);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

data.json file:
    {
      "type": "qwqw",
      "org": "asdasd",
      "pop": "asaswe",
      "results": {
        "resultId1": {
          "id": "4001",
          "type": "normal"
        },
        "resultId2": {
          "id": "5001",
          "type": "Normal"
        },
        "resultId3": {
          "id": "6001",
          "type": "Normal"
        }
      }
    }

```
Node.js Program :
//Program by Atharva Jawalkar
var fs = require("fs");
var dir = __dirname + "/data.json";
fs.readFile(dir, "utf8", function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);

  var obj2 = obj.results;

  var keysArray = Object.keys(obj2);
  var len = keysArray.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var key = keysArray[i]; 
    var value = obj2[key]; 
    console.log(key, value);
  }
});

Output:
resultId1
json_parsing_try3.js:15
Object {id: "4001", type: "normal"}
json_parsing_try3.js:15
resultId2
json_parsing_try3.js:15
Object {id: "5001", type: "Normal"}
json_parsing_try3.js:15
resultId3
json_parsing_try3.js:15
Object {id: "6001", type: "Normal"}

Here i have created data.json file and read that file in program but you can declare your json data in variable also.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code:

```
var keys = Object.keys(jsonString.results);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[keys[i]]);
}
```

should be

```
var keys = Object.keys(jsonString.results);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    console.log(keys[i]);
}
```

Notice the difference on line 3, in the console.log parameter.